# Не переносится текст на другую строку

Tags: css3

Подскажите, как исправить мой css, чтобы текст в тегах p переносился на следующую строку при уменьшении экрана.
Всё, что знала, перепробовала. Не получается. Текст параграфа не переносится.
На малых экранах просто обрезается, ибо overflow: hidden;

Вот код: https://jsfiddle.net/omh38ajg/1/
(здесь почему-то неправильно отображается, пустой контейнер слайдера)

Спасибо!

*ДОБАВЛЕНО: Как оказалось, код, приведенный ниже, работает во всех браузерах, кроме FireFox.Видимо, какое-то из свойств css требует вендорного префикса.
Хотя, это довольно странно. Свойства обычные, все поддерживаются, насколько я понимаю. Автопрефиксер не помог.*

В общем, пришлось padding-ами / margin-ами выравнивать. + пожертвовать отображением картинки в FF. Сей браузер не приручился.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

p.s. Изображение я вниз перенесу. Сейчас именно текст мне остатки мозга сломал.

```css
#slider,
ul {
  height: 250px;
}

#slider {
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

#slider li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 200px;
}

#slider ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 9000px;
  transition: left .13s linear;
  -moz-transition: left .13s linear;
  -o-transition: left .3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: left .13s linear;
  margin-left: -55px;
  font-family: century gothic;
  color: #666;
}


/*** Content ***/

.slider-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 85%;
  min-height: 180px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.slider-container h4 {
  color: #0A7FAD;
  text-shadow: -1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}

.slider-container p {
  margin: 10px -10px;
  font-weight: semi-bold;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-align: justify;
}


/*** target hooks ****/

@-webkit-keyframes slide-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  22.5% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  25% {
    left: -600px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  45% {
    left: -600px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  47.5% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    left: -1200px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    left: -1200px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  72.5% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  75% {
    left: -1800px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  95% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  98% {
    left: -1800px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#slider ul {
  -webkit-animation: slide-animation 40s infinite;
}


/* use to paused the content on mouse over */

#slider ul:hover {
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="slider-container">
        <figure>
          <a href="https://baseflat.ru/database.html">
            <h3>Однокомнатная кв</h3>
          </a>
          <h4>Ленсовета, 14</h4>
          <figcaption style="line-height: 0.5">
            <img src="https://baseflat.ru/Today-final.jpg" style="float: right; margin-left: 10px;">

            <p>Сдается 1комнатная квартира у м. Звездная, 5 минут пешком. 8 этаж в 17 этажном доме. Новая гарнитурная мебель. Бытовая техника. 23 000 рублей в месяц. Залог. + КУ</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="slider-container">
        <figure>
          <a href="https://baseflat.ru/database.html">
            <h3>Однокомнатная кв</h3>
          </a>
          <h4>Ленсовета, 14</h4>
          <figcaption style="line-height: 0.5">
            <img src="https://baseflat.ru/Today-final.jpg" style="float: right; margin-left: 10px;">

            <p>Сдается 1комнатная квартира у м. Звездная, 5 минут пешком. 8 этаж в 17 этажном доме. Новая гарнитурная мебель. Бытовая техника. 23 000 рублей в месяц. Залог. + КУ</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="slider-container">
        <figure>
          <a href="https://baseflat.ru/database.html">
            <h3>Однокомнатная кв</h3>
          </a>
          <h4>Ленсовета, 14</h4>
          <figcaption style="line-height: 0.5">
            <img src="https://baseflat.ru/Today-final.jpg" style="float: right; margin-left: 10px;">

            <p>Сдается 1комнатная квартира у м. Звездная, 5 минут пешком. 8 этаж в 17 этажном доме. Новая гарнитурная мебель. Бытовая техника. 23 000 рублей в месяц. Залог. + КУ</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="slider-container">
        <figure>
          <a href="https://baseflat.ru/database.html">
            <h3>Однокомнатная кв</h3>
          </a>
          <h4>Ленсовета, 14</h4>
          <figcaption style="line-height: 0.5">
            <img src="https://baseflat.ru/Today-final.jpg" style="float: right; margin-left: 10px;">

            <p>Сдается 1комнатная квартира у м. Звездная, 5 минут пешком. 8 этаж в 17 этажном доме. Новая гарнитурная мебель. Бытовая техника. 23 000 рублей в месяц. Залог. + КУ</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Пропишите контейнеру

```
#slider {word-wrap: break-word;}
```

Comment: Пробовала и break-word; и break-all; не срабатывает

Answer (score 1):

Меняйте max-width: 600px; на 300px, все ок.

```css
#slider {
 margin: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 margin-top: 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 position: relative;
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
<p>Сдается 1комнатная квартира у м. Звездная, 5 минут пешком. 8 этаж в 17 этажном доме. Новая гарнитурная </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Не-а... Видимо, дело не в #slider. Приложила к вопросу скриншот результата. Отступы тоже меняла. Не в них дело. А в том, что не переносится текст при уменьшении экрана.

Comment: При уменьшении экрана только через медиа @media. Для каждой точке прописываете ширину контейнера.

Comment: Ширина контейнера меняется, насколько я вижу. Это даже по фону видно (граница контейнера видна). Она указана в процентах width: 90%; А max-width: 600px; - это просто максимальная ширина.

Comment: тут пример с медиа https://jsfiddle.net/spoon100500/4atpg9os/

Comment: Мой код попробуйте. Кусочками, возможно, оно и работает. а целиком - нет